# Accessing Child XML

Tags: xml, child-nodes

I have this code below to retrieve the products from the XML further down, I can get to any children but the Merchant logo URL. If someone could please let me know how to reach the Merchant logo URL.

```
foreach ($productsResult->Products->Product as $result) {

echo "<a href=".$result->Offer->Url." target='_blank'><img class='productImg' src=".$result->Offer->Images[0]->Image->Url."/></a>"; 
echo "<p><b class='price'>£".$result->Offer->Price->Price."</b></p><br>";
echo "<p><img src=".$result->Offer->Merchant[0]->Name->Logo->Url."/></p>"; *// This is where I need help*
echo "<p class='title'>".$result->Offer->Title.".</p><a class='goToStore w3-btn w3-blue' href=".$result->Offer->Url." target='_blank'><b>Visit Store</b></a>";
```

```html
<Products>
 <Product> 
  <Offer>
   <Title></Title>
   <Description> </Description>
   <Images>
    <Image available="true">
    <Url></Url>
    <Height></Height>
    <Width></Width>
    </Image>
   <Merchant>
    <Name></Name>
    <Logo>
     <Url>The URL I need</Url>
     <Width></Width>
     <Height></Height>
     </Logo>
     </Merchant>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using an index? I looks like it should just be:

```
$result->Offer->Merchant->Logo->Url
```

Comment: Hi Zach, thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I have tried '$result->Offer->Merchant->Logo->Url' but unfortunately it still doesn't picking up the merchant logo url while I don't have any problems to get to the other child nodes.